# Trouble connecting FTDI device

Tags: visual-c++, usb, ftdi

I am trying to use the second example code for Visual C++ (http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Soft...SSE/FTCSPI.htm) To connect to the FT2232H Mini Module. My code works and indicates no device is connected when none is. However, when i connect the board and then run the code i recieve the attached message (the device is used by another application). I am not sure why i am getting this message. Any input greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FT2232 has two different drivers.  One that presents the device as a serial port and one that allows the developer to use a custom interface.  Odds are that you have the Virtual Com Port (VCP) driver installed instead of the D2XX driver.

See: http://www.ftdichip.com/Products/ICs/FT2232H.htm

Comment: It's now considered answered by accepting the answer.  It will of course still be visible for anyone else who may have the same problem.  And if someone has more to contribute they can still submit an answer.  All by design to get the highest quality QA.